# How to wrap result of an async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

How can I wrap the result of an async method into a my own wrapper class (MyEnvelop) and return it like a task?

I use a custom Envelope class for returning results from my Data Access component back to Business Layer.
This works fine with sync methods, but how can I return the result of type MyEnvelope in async mode?

**Updated** the code sample:

```
  public async Task<MyEnvelope<Customer>> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
    {
        using (var nw = new NWRepository())
        {
        Customer result = await  nw.DoSomethingAsync<Customer>(keyValues);
        return // here I would like to return new MyEnvelope<Customer>(result)
               // wrapped in Task as shown in the signature
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is that:

```
public async Task<MyEnvelope<Customer>> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
{
    using (var nw = new NWRepository())
    {
         Customer c = await  nw.FindAsync<Customer>(keyValues);
          return new MyEnvelope<Customer>(c);
    }
 }
```

you then call the method like that:

```
MyEnvelope<Customer> customer = await FindAsync(p1, p2, p3);
```

Remember `await` will return the `Result` of a `Task<T>` which is of type `T` not the `Task` object itself.

Comment: Ok, I got the await thing, but in your sample you return MyEnvelope<Customer>, but I need Task<MyEnvelope<Customer>>...?
Not sure if we mean the same..It has to be MyEnvelope<Customer> must be wrapped in a Task<MyEnvelope<Customer>> because the calling method expects a Task

Comment: No you don't, when you use the keyword async the type you return is the type inside the task.

Comment: Aaaaah, now I see, I first thought it should be Task.FromResult. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done because you need the task to resolve before you can pass it to `MyEnvelope`. The closest you can get is to remove the `async/await` keywords which unwrap the task and get `Task<Customer>`.

```
public Task<Customer> FindAsync(params object[] keyValues)
{
    using (var nw = new NWRepository())
    {
        return nw.DoSomethingAsync<Customer>(keyValues)
    }
}
```